# Specialized template methods with complex numbers class

Tags: c++, template

Suppose I have a class of complex numbers called `Complex` and I wish to implement a class of generic matrices with transpose operation.

`double`s and `int`s don't require special care, but you have to calculate the conjugate of complex numbers to transpose. Therefore, I implemented a "specialized `transpose()`".

```
template <class T> 
Matrix<T> Matrix<T>::transpose() const
{
    Matrix<T> matrix(_cols, _rows);

    unsigned int i, j;

    for (i = 0; i < _rows ; ++i)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < _cols; ++j)
        {
            matrix(j, i) = (*this)(i, j);
        }
    }

    return matrix;
}

template <> 
Matrix<Complex> Matrix<Complex>::transpose() const
{
    Matrix<Complex> matrix(_cols, _rows);

    unsigned int i, j;

    for (i = 0; i < _rows ; ++i)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < _cols; ++j)
        {
            matrix(j, i) = (*this)(i, j).conj();
        }
    }

    return matrix;
}
```

As you can see, there's a severe code repetition. Is there any way I can deal with it (like using helper methods)?

References from Wikipedia:

- [Transpose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transpose)
- [Conjugate transpose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_transpose)

Comment: Transpose and conjugate transpose are two different operations. The normal transposition of a complex matrix works just like normal transposition for a real/int matrix.

Comment: Do you really need to make a new matrix and return it every time you do this operation? This seems very memory inefficient if you are dealing with large matrices. The other option is to simply transpose the class-matrix.

Comment: Yes, in the school excerice we're reuqired not to change the object but return a new one.

Comment: By the way, specialized method - where to i implement them and how? (for example, declare in hpp and implement in cpp)?

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to review this without the whole definition of `Matrix`, but I'll have a stab.

Firstly, I'd distinguish between `transpose()` and `transposed()`.  The former would mutate an existing `Matrix` with no extra memory overhead, and the latter more like what we have here, creating a new `Matrix` without modifying the original:

```
template <class T> 
Matrix<T> Matrix<T>::transposed() const
{
    Matrix m{*this};
    m.transpose();
    return m;
}
```

The in-place `transpose()` would then just be

```
template<class T> 
auto& Matrix<T>::transpose() noexcept(std::is_nothrow_swappable_v<T>)
{
    for (std::size_t i = 0;  i < _rows;  ++i) {
        for (std::size_t j = i;  j < _cols;  ++j) {
            std::swap((*this)(j, i), (*this)(i, j));
        }
    }

    return *this;
}
```

I would implement the conjugation as a separate pass, and make it more generic, as there are other functions we'd like to apply to all elements:

```
template<class T>
template<typename Func>
auto& Matrix<T>::transform(Func f)
{
    std::ranges::transform(data, data.begin(), f);
}
```

Then we can use `transform(std::conj)` to form the complex conjugate of all the matrix elements (assuming that `Complex` is an alias of some instantiation of `std::complex<>`).  And remember that `std::conj()` is well-defined for integer and floating-point types, so you could consider using it always¹.

---

¹ It's not as simple as that, because `std::conj(IntegerOrDouble)` returns a `std::complex<double>`, but we need the same type as the argument.  See [G. Sliepen's answer](/a/281599/75307) for a workable alternative.

Answer (score 1):

## Conjugate `int`s and `double`s as well

Instead of having a generic template that does not conjugate its elements, and a specialization for `Complex` that does conjugate, just calculate the conjugate for all types. Of course, `int` and `double` don't have a `.conj()` member function, but this can be solved by creating an out-of-class `conj()` function that calls `.conj()` for `Complex`, and just returns the original value for other types (by assuming those are real numbers).

```
template <class T>
T conj(T value) {
    return value;
}

template <>
Complex conj(Complex value) {
    return value.conj();
}

template <class T>
auto Matrix<T>::transpose() const
{
    Matrix<T> matrix(_cols, _rows);

    for (unsigned i = 0; i < _rows; ++i) {
        for (unsigned j = 0; j < _cols; ++j) {
            matrix(j, i) = conjugate((*this)(i, j));
        }
    }

    return matrix;
}
```

Now there is no code duplication anymore, and you can even add support to conjugate other types, without having to change the `transpose()` function. You can also make it work like [`std::begin()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/begin), and have it call `.conj()` for all types who have that member function, and perhaps limit the version that just returns the input to the built-in number types. This is easy with C++20's concepts:

```
template <typename T>
concept conjugatable = requires (T x) {
    x.conj();
};

template <conjugatable T>
T conj(T value) {
    return value.conj();
}

template <typename T> requires std::is_arithmetic_v<T>
T conj(T value) {
     return value;
}
```

Note that there is also [`std::conj()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex/conj), but it only works for `std::complex`. Overloading functions from the `std::` namespace should not be done, but you can pull `std::conj()` into the global namespace by writing:

```
using std::conj;
```

And then calling `conj()` without `std::` will then also work for `std::complex`, and thus your `transpose()` function will also be able to work with that type.

All the above can be combined with Toby Speight's answer.

Comment: I guess this is taking the other assumption to me (i.e. that `Complex` isn't an alias of some `std::complex<>` type).  I'm not sure why anyone wouldn't use the standard library for a complex number, but this does show how to use the same technique for the non-standard version.  BTW, it's probably worth mentioning that the `using std::conj;` can be local to the `transpose()` implementation - I've seen a propensity for declaring these aliases at file scope here on CR.

Comment: If `using std::conj;`, do we need to remove our `std::is_arithmetic` version, to avoid an ambiguous match?

Comment: @TobySpeight No. `std::conj()` always returns a `std::complex`, even if the input is a scalar. That's not what we want here. And the match will not be ambiguous; our own version will take precedence over the one we bring in with `using`.

Comment: Ah, I missed that the return type isn't the same as the argument type!  And thanks for confirming the lack of ambiguity - I really wasn't sure about that.

Comment: As for bringing the `using` into `transpose()`, that's a good point. But I think that would only make sense if our own definitions for `conj()` were also inside `transpose()`. If you don't want a `::conj()` to be visible outside `transpose()`, maybe everything should be put into a detail namespace.